# How to use OR in idiorm SQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, idiorm

I am  developing an application using idiorm(https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm) for fetching data from database.

Here is my piece of code:

```
$messages = Model::factory('Messages')->where('from_user_id','1')->find_many();
```

I want to include an or statement that `where->('to_user_id','1')`

How can I put this as an OR statement in my Idiorm query?

Comment: Dare I suggest you `RT"Fragrant"M` [which is here](http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I know its a place of last resort, but give it a go. It took me 3 minutes to find it in there, how long did it take for you to write this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like what the manual is telling you to do for an OR condition

```
$messages = Model::factory('Messages')
                   ->where_any_is(
                                  array(
                                         array('from_user_id' => 1),
                                         array('to_user_id' => 1)
                                       )
                                  )    
                   ->find_many();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with idiorm, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/blob/master/idiorm.php#L1363-L1370) you should be able to use `where_raw` to build your own where clause:

```
    /**
     * Add a raw WHERE clause to the query. The clause should
     * contain question mark placeholders, which will be bound
     * to the parameters supplied in the second argument.
     */
    public function where_raw($clause, $parameters=array()) {
        return $this->_add_where($clause, $parameters);
    }
```

Something like `->where_raw('from_user_id = ? OR to_user_id = ?', array(1, 1))`